# Server-sent events SpringBoot - Angular 7

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, websocket

I'm using `SpringBoot 2.2.6` and `Angular 7`. For some reasons I need to call frontend by backend without the frontend having forwarded any calls.

The code flow should start from backend `REST Controller` that should call an `Angular` service (or something else), I have read that I must use `Socket` but I can't find an example or a tutorial that reflects my needs.

Can you address me to a right solution or tutorial?

------------------- UPDATE -----------------

Thanks for all your response, I have tried different solution but noone works as expected. I have found the follow `TypeScript` code to intercept the event from `Angular`:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
   this.connect();
  }

  connect(): void {
   let source = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/auth/streamsource');
   source.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
   let n: any;
   n = JSON.parse(event.data);
   console.log(event.data); 
   });
  }
}
```

But when the `LoginComponent` is load it calls the follow backend endpoint in loop:

```
@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping("/streamsource")
public Flux<String> streamEvents() {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
              .map(sequence -> "Flux - " + LocalTime.now().toString());
}
```

I have tried also with:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = "/streamsource", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SseEmitter stream() throws IOException {
    SseEmitter notifier = new SseEmitter();     
    notifier.send(SseEmitter.event().data("hello"));

    return notifier;    
}
```

with same results..
The flow I want to achieve is:

1. A customer start (with his own portal) an IDP initialized SSO and a call an endpoint who is filtered by `SpringSecurity`
2. If the authentication succeded, Spring redirect the flow to a controller specified by me
3. from this damned controller I want to send a token to my frontend

Is it possible?

Comment: The initial connection is always made by the browser… right..?

Answer (score -1):

Sockets is an option and so is Server Sent Events as well.

**Server-sent events:**
Server-sent events(SSE) opens a HTTP connection and send updates to all the subscribed clients continuously.

**WebSockets:**
WebSockets is used for bidirectional communication between client and server.

**HTTP long-polling:**
Long-polling opens an HTTP request which stays open till updates are received.

Take a look at below link for the difference :
https://aquil.io/articles/a-comparison-between-websockets-server-sent-events-and-polling

If only backend needs to call the frontend, then SSE is the right choice.
To create SSE streaming endpoint :

```
@GetMapping(path = "/stream-flux", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> streamFlux() {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
      .map(sequence -> "Flux - " + LocalTime.now().toString());
}
```

Consume Server Sent Events :

```
public void consumeServerSentEvent() {
    WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/sse-server");
    ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>> type
     = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {};

    Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream = client.get()
      .uri("/stream-sse")
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToFlux(type);

    eventStream.subscribe(
      content -> logger.info("Time: {} - event: name[{}], id [{}], content[{}] ",
        LocalTime.now(), content.event(), content.id(), content.data()),
      error -> logger.error("Error receiving SSE: {}", error),
      () -> logger.info("Completed!!!"));
}
```

Take a look at below link for full implementation details :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29255299)

Comment: @MarcoForberg Added brief details. Thank you for the assistance.